# how to parse the json response which starts with an array

Tags: java, loops

response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "e9299032e8a34d168def176af7d62da3",
    "createdAt": "Nov 8, 2017 9:46:40 AM",
    "model": {
      "id": "eeed0b6733a644cea07cf4c60f87ebb7",
      "name": "color",
      "app_id": "main",
      "created_at": "May 11, 2016 11:35:45 PM",
      "model_version": {}
    },
    "input": {
      "id": "df6eae07cd86483f811c5a2202e782eb",
      "data": {
        "concepts": [],
        "metadata": {},
        "image": {
          "url": "http://www.sachinmittal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/47559184-image.jpg"
        }
      }
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "hex": "#f59b2d",
        "webSafeHex": "#ffa500",
        "webSafeColorName": "Orange",
        "value": 0.0605
      },
      {
        "hex": "#3f1303",
        "webSafeHex": "#000000",
        "webSafeColorName": "Black",
        "value": 0.2085
      },
      {
        "hex": "#a33303",
        "webSafeHex": "#8b0000",
        "webSafeColorName": "DarkRed",
        "value": 0.3815
      },
      {
        "hex": "#000000",
        "webSafeHex": "#000000",
        "webSafeColorName": "Black",
        "value": 0.34275
      },
      {
        "hex": "#f7ce93",
        "webSafeHex": "#ffdead",
        "webSafeColorName": "NavajoWhite",
        "value": 0.00675
      }
    ],
    "status": {}
  }
]
```

need to parse  this reponse in json. Please  help me out.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.  What result did you expect, and what result did you actually get?

Comment: There are so many different answers you can get just based on the different libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
    try{

        JSONArray array= new JSONArray(Yourresponse);
        for(int i=0; i<=array.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);
            String id= jsonObject.getString("id");
            String created_at= jsonObject.getString("createdAt");
            String model_id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("model").getString("id");
            String app_id=jsonObject.getJSONObject("model").getString("app_id");

     //So On... Depends on your requirements. It's just an idea!
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```